# User defined function which I can use in all of my controllers

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a project and I'm using ZendFramework, also I'm a newbie in this Framework.

So my problem is,

I want to create a user defined function that I can use in all the controllers. Example: I want to create a function that will validate an input field in which I'll use trim, htmlspecialchars and mysql_real_escape_string.  I want to access this function in all the controllers.

I have a solution for this which is I'll create this function in every controller that I have, which I think is not the best solution.

Thanks

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If so, consider marking this answer as accepted. This is usually how people thank each other on SO.

Comment: @Liyali: yes, it works great, I just have some trouble in the syntax of zendframework, I use the $this->_helper->myHelper($param) to call helper that I wrote on the folder "helpers" on controllers. Thank you very much

Answer (score 8):

A base controller is a solution, but not the best to me. You should write your own **Action Helper**, they are meant to do it.

> Action Helpers allow developers to inject **runtime and/or on-demand
>   functionality into any Action Controllers** that extend
>   Zend_Controller_Action. Action Helpers aim to minimize the necessity
>   to extend the abstract Action Controller in order to inject common
>   Action Controller functionality.

More information [here in the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelper.introduction).

Let's see how to register your Action Helper path, add this in your application.ini:

```
resources.frontController.actionHelperPaths.My_Controller_Action_Helper = "My/Controller/Action/Helper/"
```

where *My* is the name of you custom library.

And in the path `My/Controller/Action/Helper/` you can add a file `MyActionHelper.php` as follow:

```
class My_Controller_Action_Helper_MyActionHelper extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function direct($input)
    {
        $output = mysql_real_escape_string($input);
        // trim, etc.
        return $output;
    }
}
```

That's all you need to do! Finally, you can access your action helper from any controller using `$this->_helper->myActionHelper($input);`.

If you need to validate an input coming from a form, take a look at [Zend_Form](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.form.introduction.html) and [Zend_Filter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.filter.introduction.html). Zend_Filter can natively [StripTags](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.filter.set.html#zend.filter.set.striptags) and [TrimString](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.filter.set.html#zend.filter.set.stringtrim), it's even a better way to do it.

Comment: That's great, I'll try this. I also tried before the action helper in Zend framework by registering Helpers with brokers but it didn't work. I'll follow your code, also I have another question. how can I access/call the function that I'd created in the controller. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by call functions created in your controllers? What are these functions? Your controllers should only hold **Actions**, and optionally an `init()` method and hook methods ([pre/post]Dispatch), maybe you could also have `private functions` used by your actions, but that's all basically.

Comment: Oops my Bad, I mean how can I call the function that I'd created "into" my Controllers.

@Liyali: I can do that by creating individual function in my controllers but it's better to create a function that all my controllers can access

Comment: Simply call  $this->_helper->myActionHelper($input); from your controller. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create file Util.php put it inside library folder
and add as many functions you want into it then open index.php (inside public folder)

add

```
require_once 'Util.php';
```

after line

```
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
```

So for e.g your Util.php will migh look like

```
    function mysql_real_escape_string($value)
    {
    return $value 
    }

    function logger($value)
    {
      Zend_Regsitry::get('logger')->log($value);
    }

  function _T($translate)
{
return Zend_Registry::get('translator')->translate($translate);
}
```

Now all of these functions are global and you are free to call them from anywhere in your zf application . I do this with my every ZF project . Adding functions here for translation or logging purpose can be really time saver .

Answer (score 0):

The Zend Framework have [Zend_Controller_Action_Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html).